# Не могу закрепить сообщение пользователя, Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['pin'])
async def piim(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(f"{bot.pin_chat_message}")
```

Comment: Если вам подошёл ответ примите его иначе на ваши вопросы желания отвечать не будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понимаю, вы хотите закрепить сообщение, на которое пользователь ответил командой: /pin, если да, то вот решение:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["pin"])
async def pinHandler(message: types.Message):
    await bot.pin_chat_message(message.chat.id, message.reply_to_message.message_id)
    await message.answer("Прикрепил")
```